# Syntax and missing type specifier errors at global array initialization in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, global

For the following lines of code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

void telephonebill();
void add();
void edit();
void readFile();
void display();


 string names[100];
 string addresses[100];
 int tn[100];
 int numCalls[100];
 int trunkCalls[100];
 int numMobCalls[100];
 int isdnNum[100];
 int dueD[100];
 int paymentD[100];
 int numC = 0;
```

I am getting these lines of error:

```
  1>Project.cpp(12): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'names'
  1>Project.cpp(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
  1>Project.cpp(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
  1>Project.cpp(13): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'addresses'
  1>Project.cpp(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
  1>Project.cpp(13): error C2086: 'int string' : redefinition
  1>Project.cpp(12) : see declaration of 'string'
  1>Project.cpp(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

What is the problem with the declaration of these arrays?

Comment: Which line is line 12? And what is *before* line 12? You are including `<string>`? You are doing `using namespace std;` (which many recommend against) or `using std::string;`?

Comment: You presumably forgot a `;` before the declaration of `names`.

Comment: line 12 is          string names[100];
and before it is    void display();

Comment: Instead of a bunch of 100-length arrays, you probably want a C++ container filled with a simple structure that contains that data. What you have here is a complete mess.

Comment: You're not `using` the standard namespace in this source file. As a result, `string` is unknown. `std::string` will work (and is recommended), or (shudder) place `using namespace std;` after your includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the namespace:

You can add the following at the beginning of your file after your includes (note that in a more complex scenario this could be a problem. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))

```
using namespace std;
```

or you can specify the namespace each time you are using string: `std::string`

Comment: A lot of people recommend against `using namespace` and instead recommend specifying it literally: `std::string`. They're organized into a namespace for a reason.

Comment: Both solutions are working with this small example. But this is true that in more complex case the using namespace can create issue.

Comment: @tadman significantly more important in a *header* file than a end-point *source* file. It is worth noting, however.